# android native browser does not support higher resolution?

Tags: javascript, android, browser

I decided to write something for Android using native browser and Canvas / JS.
So i have an Android tablet with screen resolution 1536x2048. I checked window resolution with this code:

```
alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'x' 
+ document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

so the result was 980x1080. Why?

upd: in "full version mode" situation still the same

Comment: Did you try [these?](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp). It says there's no official standard, so that may the issue.

Comment: Those may be CSS pixels, which equate to Android's density-independent pixels and take screen density into account.

Comment: @Marius it shows 980x1081 :]

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but why don't they equate to screen pixels??

Comment: Because density-independent pixels are a great way of normalizing screen sizes to relate to real-life sizes (saying 40dp is always 1/4 of an inch), while taking advantage of the extra pixels.

Comment: You can, however, check out `window.devicePixelRatio` as a multiplier to convert between device-independent pixels and screen pixels.